# TabLayout jumps to start of its witdth after notifyItemChanged()

Tags: android, kotlin, android-tablayout, android-viewpager2

I'm building quiz app and all the time I have trouble with notifying RecyclerView about updated item.
DiffUtil didn't work for me, anyway - I can use adapter.notifyItemChanged() but after this call my TabLayout jumps to start of it's width.
I have set onClickListener to my floatingButton to be sure that it's notifyItemChanged() issue.
Am I doing something wrong?

## Fragment

```kotlin
class TestFragment : Fragment() {
    private lateinit var viewModel: TestViewModel
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val binding: FragmentTestBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            inflater,
            R.layout.fragment_test,
            container,
            false
        )
        val args = TestFragmentArgs.fromBundle(requireArguments())
        val viewModelFactory = TestViewModelFactory(args.course)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory).get(TestViewModel::class.java)
        binding.viewModel = viewModel
        binding.lifecycleOwner = viewLifecycleOwner
        val adapter = PagerAdapter(ClickListener { questionDatabase: QuestionDatabase, string: String ->
            val questionUpdated = questionDatabase.apply { answer = string }
            viewModel.updateAnswer(questionDatabase, questionUpdated)
        })
        binding.viewPager.adapter = adapter
        TabLayoutMediator(binding.tabLayout, binding.viewPager) { tab: TabLayout.Tab, i: Int ->
            tab.text = (i + 1).toString()
        }.attach()
        viewModel.pytania.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            adapter.differ.submitList(it)
        })

        viewModel.score.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            if (it != null) {
                findNavController().navigate(
                    TestFragmentDirections.actionTestFragmentToScoreFragment(it)
                )
                viewModel.score.value = null
            }
        })
        binding.bttnFinish.setOnClickListener {
            adapter.notifyItemChanged(binding.viewPager.currentItem)
        }
        return binding.root
    }
}
```

## ViewModel

```kotlin
class TestViewModel(
    test: String
): ViewModel() {
    private val _pytania = MutableLiveData<List<QuestionDatabase>>()
    val pytania: LiveData<List<QuestionDatabase>>
        get() = _pytania
    val score = MutableLiveData<Int?>()
    init {
        val listOfQuestions = mutableListOf<QuestionDatabase>()
        for (x in 1..15) {
            listOfQuestions.add(
                QuestionDatabase(
                    question = "Question $x",
                    answerA = "AnswerA",
                    answerB = "AnswerB",
                    answerC = "AnswerC",
                    answerD = "AnswerD",
                    correctAnswer = "AnswerD",
                    image = 0,
                    questionNumber = 0
                )
            )
        }
        _pytania.value = listOfQuestions.toList()
    }
    fun updateAnswer(questionDatabase: QuestionDatabase, questionUpdated: QuestionDatabase) {
    _pytania.value = _pytania.value?.replace(questionDatabase, questionUpdated)
    }
}
```

## ViewPagerAdapter

```kotlin
class PagerAdapter(
    private val clickListener: ClickListener
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder>() {
    private val differCallBack = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<QuestionDatabase>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: QuestionDatabase, newItem: QuestionDatabase): Boolean {
            return oldItem.question == newItem.question
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: QuestionDatabase, newItem: QuestionDatabase): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }
    }
    val differ = AsyncListDiffer(this, differCallBack)
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        return ViewHolder.from(parent)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(differ.currentList[position], clickListener)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return differ.currentList.size
    }
}
class ViewHolder private constructor(val binding: VpItemQuestionBinding): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(
    binding.root
) {
    fun bind(
        question: QuestionDatabase,
        clickListener: ClickListener
    ) {
        binding.question = question
        binding.onClickListener = clickListener
        binding.executePendingBindings()
    }
    companion object {
        fun from(parent: ViewGroup): ViewHolder {
            val layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            val binding = VpItemQuestionBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, parent, false)
            return ViewHolder(binding)
        }
    }
}
class ClickListener(val clickListener: (QuestionDatabase, string: String) -> Unit) {
    fun onClick(question: QuestionDatabase, string: String) = clickListener(question, string)
}
```

## Before notifyItemChanged()

[image: before onClick]

## After notifyItemChanged()

[image: after onClick]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't post screenshots of your code as these are hard to search. Instead, [edit] your question to include the code itself